# How to limit products category based per user in magento 1.9.1.0?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, category-products, user

I want to limit products category based per user. For example, If I have added free category under 10 products. Users only can order 1 to 7 products within free 10 products. Any idea regrading this?

Comment: You need to create custom extension and write the logic during the event checkout_product_add_after

Comment: which location I need to write event checkout_product_add_after?

Comment: You need to create your own module and create a observer with event checkout_product_add_after.